# How to search value in two or more different fields in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My node model contains the following fields in the user collection:

```
firstName: {
   type: String,
},
lastName: {
   type: String
},
mobile: {
   type: String,
   unique: true
},
email: {
   type: String,
   index: true,
   unique: true
}
```

And now suppose I have the following records in collection:
[image]

Now when I search record with the following conditions it wasn't returns anything:

```
"$or": [
{
  "firstName": {
    "$regex": "Sunil Narine",
    "$options": "i"
  }
},
{
  "lastName": {
    "$regex": "Sunil Narine",
    "$options": "i"
  }
},
{
  "email": {
    "$regex": "Sunil Narine",
    "$options": "i"
  }
},
{
  "mobile": {
    "$regex": "Sunil Narine"
  }
}
```

]

If I just pass `Sunil` or `Narine` then it returns result but when I pass the combined value of both `firstName` and `lastName` i.e. `Sunil Narine` then it wasn't returning the result.

I also tried the following different things too but wasn't working any:

```
"$regex": /^Sunil Narine$/,
"$options": "i"
OR
"$regex": /$Sunil Narine.*/,
"$options": "i"
OR
"$regex": /^Sunil Narine/,
"$options": "i"
```

So anyone have idea to solve this issue.
Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/index.html#text-search)?

Comment: No @Joe, It won't help me.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you want to get the result if it contains either Sunil or Narain.

This regex will match on either Sunil or Narine.

```
"$regex": /(Sunil)|(Narine)/g
```

Comment: Thanks, Ibrahim for your reply.
So as per your answer, I need to replace space with pipeline `|` right?

Because `Sunil Narine` is just an example actually there should be any value